# Is there a better way to get the nth element in a list of unknown length?

Tags: python

Suppose you want to make a dictionary out of a list such that:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
d = {1: 2, 3: 4}
```

Here is my solution:

```
def autodict(*args):
    container = list(args)
    #                      ↓ especially this
    return {arg: container[container.index(arg) + 1] for arg in args if arg != container[-1]} if len(args) > 1 else set(args)
```

Is there any better way to do this or is an explicit for loop better at this point? (that works for any iterable as well?)

```
autodict([1,2,3,4,5]) -> {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}
autodict(1) -> {1}
autodict(1,2) -> {1: 2}
```

Comment: Iterate through `l`, consume two elements `k` and `v` for each step, let `d[k]=v`. This is O(n), while your suggested solution is O(n^2) in the length of `l`.

Comment: This will do it:  `d = dict(zip(l[0::2],l[1::2]))`

Comment: Also, I assume your first example line is wrong, and you actually wanted `autodict([1,2,3,4,5]) -> {1: 2, 3: 4}`.  If I'm wrong, the Alex R has the right code below.

Comment: And one more thing:  `{1}` is not a dictionary.  It's a set.

Comment: So there's no nifty one-liner for it and the o(n) solution uses tuple unpacking ( k , v = enumerate(l) ), right?

Comment: Are you not paying attention?  There are TWO one liners here, depending on what result you wanted.

Comment: True, but a singleton looks better than {1: None}

Comment: I meant gspr not you, thanks for the nifty solution :)

Comment: What does your question have to do with getting the nth element of a list of unknown length?

Comment: You can generalize alex's solution if I wanted the step to be 2 , for example

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry, I didn't see that you posted the solution as a comment. Your version is of course correct if the step is two. I'll delete my answer if you want to post yours.

Comment: Since we haven't heard what the OP's requirements really are, let's just leave it the way it is.  You have both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` for that:

```py
dict(zip(l, l[1:]))
```

If `l = [1,2,3,4,5]` you get as output `{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}`

**Edit:**
If you want the output to match your first example, you can use a step as suggested by Tim Roberts:

```
dict(zip(l[0::2],l[1::2]))
```

However, with this version you'll need to take take of the last elements yourself if you want them to be included in your result as this version only outputs `{1: 2, 3: 4}` (i.e. the `5` is "lost")